# Unresolved external symbol linking to a VS6 library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unresolved-external

I've got an NIUSB8452 DAQ, with which the vendor thoughtfully provided ni845x.lib and ni845x.h so I could use C instead of LabView to do my data reading. However, I'm having some problems with getting the lib working in VisualStudio 2015. The first point of alarm is probably that their documentation says it is compatible with VS6, but I've seen other people on here successfully use libraries for VS6 on VS15, so, I hope I can also be so beautiful.

The problem that I am having *right now* is that on a build, I'm getting linker errors that read something like

```
unresolved external symbol @ni845xStatusToString@12 referenced in function (function name follows)
```

While googling around, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585440/unresolved-symbols-when-linking-against-vc6-dll-lib) which mentioned dumpbin /exports. To check that I wasn't running into a 32/64 bit error like the poster described (since I wasn't really sure how to diagnose this, it seemed as good a place to start as any), I ran dumpbin /exports on the external lib. I got a pile of public symbols, including

```
FF06 __imp__ni845xStatusToString@12
FF06 _ni845xStatusToString@12
```

I'm definitely **not** seeing @ni845xStatusToString@12, which is what VisualStudio is complaining about being unresolved.

What's the difference between @ni845xStatusToString@12 and _ni845xStatusToString12? What does the presence of the latter and the absence of the former indicate that I am doing wrong with this import?

**Notes**

- The lib and header have been included in the file as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059167/3421124), with the exception that I gave a full path to the lib for #4, which I think implies you only need the filename.
- I'm using extern "C" { #include ni845x.h } in my cpp file, although ni845x.h does have the #ifdef __cplusplus boilerplate in there.

Comment: Didn't see that you already tried the dumpbin things. Anyway, if it's a C only library and doesn't do the `#ifdef __cplusplus` thing, you can try including it via `extern "C"{ #include <ni845x.h> }`

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that. I do have it wrapped in `extern "C" `, although the header also has `#ifdef __cplusplus` I'm being redundant, but I don't think that would be _harmful._

Comment: well then I guess you should make sure that the functions in the header have `__declspec(dllimport)` in front of them